# Excel Convert (quote marks) " to &quote; without screwing up html links

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have an excel file that was exported from our website with quote marks " that need to be replaced with the html entity:

```
&quot;
```

This:

```
Dimensions are 7" wide by 5" tall.
```

Needs to look like:

```
Dimensions are 7&quot; wide by 5&quot; tall
```

A simple excel find and replace will do the trick, but we also have legitimate quote marks that need to stay because they are embedded in html links like this:

```
<a href="http://www.daylightcolor.com/csl/index.php?c=11" target="_blank">
```

How can we find and replace the regular quote marks while not touching any quote marks inside the a href tags?

Comment: Use a regex-based replacement with `"(?![^<]*>)` regex.

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach with `"(?![^<]*>)` regex that will replace double quotes that are not followed by `>`:

```
Sub CallReplMultiple()
Dim ptrn As String, txt As String
Dim regExp As Object

ptrn = """(?![^<]*>)"
Set regExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With regExp
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = ptrn
End With

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  For j = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j) = regExp.Replace(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value, "&quot;")
  Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Would it cut down on the loop if only [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) of `xlCellTypeConstants` was looked for?

Comment: @Jeeped: I used `UsedRange` for demo, and surely the loop can and should be adjusted for the concrete task.